# mercurial precommit infinite loop

Tags: loops, gradle, mercurial, infinite

Ok here is the problem, I'm developing an application in Java using Gradle.
I have a Gradle task that adds a license on top of each file if it does not exist.

I wanted to add a precommit hook so that when I commit the files, the Gradle task runs and changes the license on top of the files if needed. Keep in mind that the Gradle licenseFormat, may change nothing or more than 10 files at the same time, so i have no way of knowing which files are changed to add them to commit manually.

I tried this hook:

```
[hooks]
pre-commit.licenseFormat=C:/Users/pc/Dropbox/{REPOSITORIES}/{PETULANT}/format.bat
```

It simply calls a batch file that runs the Gradle command but, as I suspected, because some files are changed that are not in the current commit, the commit gets stuck and it seems like it falls into an infinite loop of calling the batch file time and time again and each time it will fire the command.
In next run of the command nothing should be changed but when the first run changed more than few files, I think the commit fires the batch file more than twice.

So the question is, how can I stop the commit hook after the very first run of the batch file and add the changed file to current or new commit?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful to include the contents of the batch file here.

Answer (score 0):

the batch file is only the command :

```html
gradlew licenseFormat
```

as I said, it runs a gradle task that will add license comments on top of the files needed, in other words, it first checks the header of the file and compares it to the one that should be there, if they are the same, then the file will not be touched but if they are not the same, it removes the header and adds the license text as comment on top of the head, if you want more in dept look the actual task is this :

```html
buildscript{
 repositories{
  mavenCentral()
  jcenter()
  maven { url = "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven" }
  maven { url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
 }
 dependencies{
  classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT'
  classpath 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:0.10.1'
  classpath 'nl.javadude.gradle.plugins:license-gradle-plugin:0.11.0'
 }
}

apply plugin: 'license'

license{
 ext.name = project.name
 ext.organization = project.organization
 ext.url = project.url
 ext.year = project.inceptionYear
 exclude '**/*.info'
 exclude '**/*.json'
 exclude '**/*.ma'
 exclude '**/*.mb'
 exclude '**/*.png'
 header new File(projectDir, 'HEADER.txt')
 sourceSets = project.sourceSets
 ignoreFailures = false
 strictCheck = true
 mapping { java = 'SLASHSTAR_STYLE'}
}
```